# Is there a free Hebrew Dictionary/Lexicon/Word List with exact pronunciations available online?

Tags: dictionary, hebrew, ipa

I just found [this](https://github.com/NLPH/NLPH_Resources), and its data looks like this:

```
verb_complement
verb_LexiconPointer
verb_LexiconItem
verb_dottedLexiconItem
verb_transliteratedLexiconItem
verb_binyan
verb_root 
complement_LexiconItem
complement_LexiconPointer
n_v_c n_v n_!v_c  n_!v  RF  LLR T_SCORE PMI RF_comp LLR_comp  
T_SCORE_comp
PMI_comp  SUM
אבד_את  16329 אבד אָבַד abd Pa'al abd את  2 105.1247  374.6289  265321.26 1818433.4 0.2806102 44.978018 0.0002829 0.6538104 1 0 1 1 3
```

Is there anything that goes beyond this and offers the *exact* pronunciation (like with IPA, International Phonetic Alphabet) for the Hebrew words? I know that Wiktionary exists, but it only has about 900 Hebrew words with IPA. I am looking for a comprehensive word list with pronunciations / stress placement / etc. For the Hebrew language.